# Most concise way of updating a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, sequence

Say I have a list of 100 unique integers ranging from 0 to 99. Now I have 10,000 new integers ranging from 0 to 199 (with duplicants of course). I want to append every new integer to the list and constantly update the list. Whenever there is a same integer already existed in the list, the old one should be removed. The updated list should still be a list of all unique integers.

My first instinct is to use `set().add()`, but set is unordered so it cannot be used to update a sequence. I managed to write the following code, which works fine. It takes 47 ms for updating 10,000 new integers to a list of 100 unqiue integers.

```
import random
from time import time

random.seed(99)
newlen = 10000
lst = list(range(100))
random.shuffle(lst)
newlst = [random.randrange(200) for _ in range(newlen)]

t0 = time()
for new in newlst:
    idx = next((i for i, n in enumerate(lst) if n == new), None)
    if idx is not None:
        lst.pop(idx)
    lst.append(new)

print(time()-t0)
```

Output:

```
0.04717659950256348
```

However, I feel like there should be faster and more concise way to update a python list. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about ```OrderedDict.fromkeys(list)```? This will remove duplicates and sort the list

Comment: I may be missing the point here, but it seems to me that all this does is make another list of unique integers in `range(100)`, of the same size, just in a different order.  What will your algorithm achieve that a second call to `random.shuffle(lst)` will not do?

So one must assume that your example is simply designed to show that repeatedly deleting values out of the middle of a list is inefficient.

It is, but what is the point in doing things that way? Is there a use-case that could not be better implemented as a set or a dict?

Comment: @BoarGules The ``lst`` and ``newlst`` here are just to show as an example. In reality I always have new integers generated by a function one by one over time, and I want to constantly update the list in place.

Comment: But why does the data structure you are using *have to be a list*, when the operation you are performing on it (repeated deletions) is known to have a time complexity of O(*n*)? (https://dev.to/global_codess/time-complexities-of-python-data-structures-3bja)

Comment: @BoarGules So, every time the list is updated, it has a new state. I just concatenate all integers to a string to represent this state. Of course the sequence is important.

Comment: I didn't say insertion sequence was unimportant. I said that a list is not the only nor necessarily the best way to preserve it. Depending on what you want to do, you might choose `OrderedDict`, `collections.deque`. or (in Python ≥ 3.6) simply `dict`.  Try this: `dic = {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}; del(dic[2]); dic[2]="new"`.  `2` will now be the last key in `dic`. All with O(1) operations.

Comment: There are various `OrderedSet` implementations available (but not in the standard library).